# Hazelcast how to indicate the time when partition migration completed

Tags: web, hazelcast

I have two nodes of web application with embedded hazelcast inside each of them. After data are put enough into the cluster, one node (A) is down.

I start up it (A) gain, and i want to recover its business. So, i need to indicate the time (or event) when all the partitions are migrated completely.

Any one give me an suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check the cluster's state by using some methods. Please see the details here: [Health Check and Monitoring](https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#health-check-and-monitoring)

Also, you can follow the cluster state on [Management Center dashboard](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/management-center/latest/manual/html/index.html#cluster-state-and-health).